# Rails logging during config/initializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Because of timing I think, when I am executing one of my initializers, I don't have access to Rails.logger.info. Is there a trick? I can't actually even find where Rails.logger is actually set up!

Answer (score 0):

i think this will solve your issue. please let me know

> RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER.info "abc"